# Will a using block close a database connection?

Tags: c#, database, using

```
using (DbConnection conn = new DbConnection())
{
    // do stuff with database
}
```

Will the `using` block call `conn.Close()`?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, it will; the implementation of `DbConnection.Dispose()` calls `Close()` (and so do its derived implementations).

Comment: Doesn't it depend on whether the derived class has overridden the Dispose(bool) method? If the derived class does not override it and call 'Close()' then the connection will not be closed at the end of the using block (when Dispose is called)

Comment: Pretty sure AL's comment is accurate as DBConnection doesn't actually override Dispose provided by System.ComponentModel.Component.  In practice though I doubt there are any DBConnection implementations that don't override Dispose and close any connections as a connection class that doesn't clean up after itself would be a pretty poor implementation.

Answer (score 8):

Yes - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close.aspx

edit: from Microsoft: "The connection is automatically closed at the end of the using block."

Comment: While a link may solve the question it also may contain more information. A small synopsis here is a nice thing to help the reader concentrate on the important points.

Answer (score 8):

A `using` block will ensure the destruction of `DbConnection` object by calling the `Dispose()` method. The `Dispose()` method will in turn call the `Close()` method and has to wait for it to finish closing the connection to the database.

Answer (score 6):

surely yes because it will dispose the connection and before disposing the inner logic of the connection calls the close.