# Is there any need to close a DbConnection if a using clause is used?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, using, dbconnection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will a using block close a database connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243398/will-a-using-block-close-a-database-connection)

Is `db.Close()` unnecessary in the following?

```
using (DbConnection db = GetDbConnection())
{
   // do data-access stuff
   // ...

   db.Close();
}
```

Comment: no, using in implementation of dispose method in DBConnection, calls db.Close(). It is unnecessary

Comment: see this great explanation of IDisposable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/538238/110933

Answer (score 13):

> Is there any need to close a DbConnection if a using clause is used?

No, there is no need to close a DbConnection if a using clause is used?

and

Yes it is unnecessary in here because when scope of `using` ends, connection will dispose meaning closing and releasing all memory.

Since `DBConnection` implements `IDisposable` interface, close function is there in the `Dispose` method of `DBConnection`.

But if some lines are after close line then it is useful

```
using (DbConnection db = GetDbConnection())
{
  // do data-access stuff
  // ...

  db.Close(); //Useless
}
```

But here it is useful

```
using (DbConnection db = GetDbConnection())
{
  // do data-access stuff
  // ...

  db.Close(); //Useful

 // Some more code
}
```

In that case you can do

```
using (DbConnection db = GetDbConnection())
{
  // do data-access stuff
  // ...

}

// Some more code which was previously inside using section.
```

Comment: +1 for nice design to manually close in case more code exists that does not use the connection. However in that case it is better not to include that code in the using block.

Comment: @Aphelion: yes, surely the code below the Close() should not be in the block

Comment: Why some more code below db.CLose() is useful?

Comment: @CuongLe: May be a code which works on values fetched after firing some query through that connection.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Good point. In that case I would recommend to store the results outside the `using` scope.

Comment: In that case, it will throw out exception because connection is actualy close, still confused

Comment: @CuongLe: What if those results are fetched before connection is closed.

Comment: if those results are fetched before connection, it is not the case "more code below db.CLose() is useful".

Comment: @CuongLe: Here more code is not useful. If some code is after `db.Close();` then closing it manually is useful.

Answer (score 4):

Just to be sure i have checked the code :)

```
   protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      if (disposing)
      {
        this._userConnectionOptions = (DbConnectionOptions) null;
        this._poolGroup = (DbConnectionPoolGroup) null;
        this.Close();
      }
      this.DisposeMe(disposing);
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

This is the implementation of **SqlConnection** which is inheriting from **DbConnection**. As you can see there is **this.Close()** method :)

Comment: I was wondering in here, `using` statement calls `Dispose()` or `Dispose(bool disposing)`

Comment: @Aphelion: pls could you also answer on this?

Comment: @CuongLe It will call `Dispose()` which is public. Its implementation will then call `Dispose(true)`.

Answer (score 2):

For what I know, when `Dispose()` method is called, `Close()` is automatically performed.
So `db.Close();` is not necessary here.

Answer (score 2):

Extracted code from the dispose implementation of the `SqlConnection` (Derived of `DbConnection`) class:

```
public void Dispose()
{
   Dispose(true);
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  if (disposing)
  {
     this.Close();
  }
  base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

The `using` keyword uses the `IDisposable` interface. The method above is the method implementation. It will close the connection.

Answer (score 1):

At the closing brace the `Dispose()` is called.

I think in the `DbConnection` the `Dispose` method will also check if the connection is closed.
So no, it probably isn't necessary, but I personally think it is good practice and improves readability and it doesn't affect performance because the `Close` will be called one way or another.