# Does OledbConnection.Dispose() close the connection?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, oledbconnection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any need to close a DbConnection if a using clause is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033998/is-there-any-need-to-close-a-dbconnection-if-a-using-clause-is-used)

Does `OledbConnection.Dispose()` close the connection?

I am aware that `SqlConnection` does but what about `OledbConnection`?

Comment: Why do you think there is a difference?

Comment: Yes. Instead of calling .Dispose, try the `using` block which will dispose the connection, as the code inside the `using` block finishes execution.

Comment: @AmiramKorach: people have talked only about `SqlConnection`. `DbConnection` is an abstract class so it depends on the actual implementation of `OledbConnection`.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, it also does.**

Source: [OleDbConnection.Dispose Method (Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325891%28v=vs.71%29)

> The Dispose method calls Close, and removes the OleDbConnection from
> the connection pool.

For detailed information see the `Remarks` section on the reference link to know about the case of releasing both managed and unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, according to the documentation on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325890(v=vs.71).aspx , `OleDbConnection.Dispose()` also does call the `OleDbConnection.Close()`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325891.aspx):

> The Dispose method calls Close, and removes the OleDbConnection from the connection pool.

Note, that the above is from the .NET Framework 1.1. But (in this case) you can count on things having not changed.

Also, you can be almost 100% sure that every class that implements `IDbConnection` will "close" the connection in the `Dispose` method - whatever that means for the particular implementation is not relevant, but it will be equivalent to calling `Close` manually.

Every implementation that does not behave that way, should be IMO considered broken.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the ultimate proof.. the actual code of the `Dispose` method, taken using a reflector:

```
// System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        this._userConnectionOptions = null;
        this._poolGroup = null;
        this.Close();
    }
    this.DisposeMe(disposing);
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If it didn't, then it can't fully dispose of it's resources. BinaryReader, BinaryWriter, etc all close the underlying stream as well