# Sorting column in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Below is my code **C#** net4 for sorting column in **GridView** but I've this error:

```
CS1502: The best overloaded method match for System.Data.DataView.DataView(System.Data.DataTable) has some invalid arguments
```

in this line why?: `DataView sortedView = new DataView(GridViewBind());`

```
public SortDirection dir
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["dirState"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["dirState"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
        }
        return (SortDirection)ViewState["dirState"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["dirState"] = value;
    }
}

protected void gridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    string sortingDirection = string.Empty;
    if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Descending;
        sortingDirection = "Desc";
    }
    else
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Ascending;
        sortingDirection = "Asc";
    }

    DataView sortedView = new DataView(GridViewBind());
    sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + sortingDirection;
    GridView1.DataSource = sortedView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}


public void GridViewBind()
{
    sql1 = " SELECT * FROM `tbl` ORDER BY empid DESC; ";

    dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql1, myConnectionString);
    dset = new DataSet();
    dset.Clear();
    dadapter.Fill(dset);
    GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();
    dadapter.Dispose();
    dadapter = null;
    myConnectionString.Close();

}
```

Comment: Please allways use 'using' for all kind of connections! Because you can be shure your connection will everytime be colsed.
More information about that you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243398/will-a-using-block-close-a-database-connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to this line

```
DataView sortedView = new DataView(GridViewBind());
```

The function `GridViewBind()` return type is `void` which is incorrect. It should return a `DataTable`.

If it returns `DataTable` then your code will work.

You need to modify your function as follow

```
public DataTable GridViewBind()
{
    sql1 = " SELECT * FROM `tbl` ORDER BY empid DESC; ";

    dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql1, myConnectionString);
    dset = new DataSet();
    dset.Clear();
    dadapter.Fill(dset);
    DataTable dt=dset.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    dadapter.Dispose();
    dadapter = null;
    myConnectionString.Close();
    return dt;

}
```

Comment: Yes the error is due to this line... but the solution?

Comment: @Hamamelis I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use DataView to sot the data.

```
public void GridViewBind()
{
sql1 = " SELECT * FROM `tbl` ORDER BY empid DESC; ";

dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql1, myConnectionString);
dset = new DataSet();
dset.Clear();
dadapter.Fill(dset);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt=dset.Tables[0];
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "empid desc";
DataTable sortedDT = dv.ToTable();
GridView1.DataSource = sortedDT;
GridView1.DataBind();
dadapter.Dispose();
dadapter = null;
myConnectionString.Close();

}
```