# Why do I need I need to implement IDisposable() on a child class

Tags: c#, idisposable, dbconnection

I wrote a class that inherits DbConnection and I'm not understanding fully why it works as it does.

At first I had this :

```
public class DatabaseConnection : DbConnection
{
    ... 
    public override void Close()
    {
        // Some stuff
    }   
    // No Dispose method
}

using(var db = new DatabaseConnection())
{
    // Some processing
}
```

The Close() method was not called, and we could see the connections staying on the MySQL server.

---

Now I have this, and **it works** (it really closes the connections, and the server is OK) :

```
public class DatabaseConnection : DbConnection, IDisposable
{
    ... 
    public override void Close()
    {
        // Some stuff
    }   

    public new void Dispose()
    {
        Close();
        base.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

using(var db = new DatabaseConnection())
{
    // Some processing
}
```

---

Why inheriting the DbConnection class and overriding the Close() method doesn't work ?

Comment: Dispose or Close ? Because the content of the Dispose method is already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Common/DBConnection.cs,fabf6c9e5bf4d9f2) that `DbConnection` does not override `Dispose`, so `Dispose` will not call `Close`.

`DbConnection` inherits from `Component`, which is where the implementation of `IDisposable` is.  You can see from the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/Component.cs,180) that its `Dispose(bool disposing)` method is `virtual`, so you should override that:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    base.Dispose(disposing)
    Close();
}
```

Comment: Some might argue that there is a "bug" in `DbConnection`, or at least in it's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.close(v=vs.110).aspx): "... close the connection by calling `Close` or `Dispose`, which are functionally equivalent." - but as we've seen, there's no guarantee that inheriting classes will maintain that function equivalency, when it could have easily have been made so (by at least having a "note to inheritors" or by explicitly coding this co-dependency).

Comment: Thanks I see the logic there. That's very confusing with all the questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243398/will-a-using-block-close-a-database-connection) showing a simple using() !

Comment: @MickaelV. it's especially confusing as (as Damien points out) the documentation says it works like that too.   The comment on the answer to your linked question is valid, though: *In practice I doubt there are any DBConnection implementations that don't override Dispose and close any connections*.  You're only noticing this because you're inheriting from the base class.

Answer (score 0):

The [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) calls the Dispose method at the end of the block.

Since the [DbConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) also implements the IDisposable interface, the using block in the first snippet calls the inherited Dispose method.

The connection stays alive perhaps because you override the Close function, but I'm not sure in this, please correct me if I'm wrong.